# How to type this when using apply

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I type the `this` argument when my function receives it?

```
import { generatePath } from 'react-router-dom';

type generatePathParamsType = Parameters<typeof generatePath>[1];

// Following type definition of 'this' is not working
const generatePathFactory = function (this: typeof ENV_DASHBOARD) {
  return function (args: generatePathParamsType = {}) {
    // 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
    return generatePath(this.PATH, args);
  };
};

const ENV_DASHBOARD = {
  PATH: "/dashboard/:environmentId",
  generatePath: generatePathFactory.apply(this),
  TITLE: "Dashboard"
};

console.log(ENV_DASHBOARD.generatePath({ environmentId: "1" })); // '/dashboard/1'
```

[Demo at codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-grothendieck-zpnzn2?file=/src/index.ts:329-366)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Comment: In `generatePath: generatePathFactory.apply(this),`, `this` does _not_ refer to `ENV_DASHBOARD`...

Comment: @Ivar the question is about self reference in objects, no typing the `this` argument

Comment: I don't really see why the answers to the linked question don't apply here. Both questions are referencing `this` in an array literal, the `this` means the same in both question, regardless of whether you use it as an argument or not. You can't directly reference the object literal itself the way you want it. The answers to the proposed duplicates apply. (T.J. Crowder's and Felix Kling's answers are most likely your best options if you don't want to repeat the call every time you access `generatePath`.)